# How do you determine why Google Analytics oAuth access is being revoked

Tags: google-analytics, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

My app allows users to oAuth their Google Analytics so that we can provide analytics and reporting to our users. We have over 1000 connected accounts but one of them has had an issue where it disconnects from us after some period of time. When it's first connected to us it works fine but after a seemingly random period of time (sometimes hours, sometimes days) it will return 401 for every request. According to [Google's error documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/errors) this indicates that the auth token is invalid or expired. Our user claims that they did not revoke access to our app and our app was present when they checked the [current connected apps](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions).

After going through [Google's oAuth Documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration) we determined it must be one of the 4 documented cases, but determined that none of them could be the case since

1. The user claims that they did not revoke access to our app and the app was present in their permissions
2. The token stops working within hours, so it couldn't have timed out after 6 months
3. We don't request Gmail scope, so changing a password wouldn't affect our access. Even if this did, the user wouldn't be changing their password every few hours/days
4. The user isn't oAuthed to 50 apps. From a screenshot, we can see that there are less than 5

We've gone through the process of having them reconnect their Google Analytics to us and that's worked for a short period of time, but then it begins returning 401s. We've also had them try to use different users, profiles, and even have their Google admin connect to us and they all fail after a certain amount of time.

The specific error we're seeing is

`{"code":401,"errors":[{"domain":"global","location":"Authorization","locationType":"header","message":"Login Required","reason":"required"}],"message":"Login Required"}`

As noted earlier, this doesn't occur for any of our other 1000+ connected accounts.

My main question here how can we determine why the Google Analytics oAuth access is being revoked? With this information, we can hopefully figure out how to stop this from happening.